# Is Pikachu female?

Tags: pokemon

So I wonder if Pikachu is female or male, because in the Movie *Pokémon - I choose you!*, Pikachu was voiced by a woman. If he was male, I don't think they would voice that Part by a woman.

Also, Ash’s Pikachu has no heart shape at the end of it’s tail, but that proves nothing, because that wasn’t a Thing when Pomémon was created.

Comment: Obviously you've never heard of the Simpsons..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Pikachu's gender ever confirmed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12382/) - see OP's self-answer there, which has the same "No Togepi has gone before" argument than the answer below v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ash's Pikachu is male.** This is confirmed in the anime episode *[Where No Togepi Has Gone Before!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP142)*, which aired after Diamond/Pearl introduced heart-shaped tails for female Pikachu. In that episode, a Togepi uses Attract on both Pikachu and Meowth, and it works on both occasions. Since Meowth is known to be male, and Attract only works on Pokémon of the opposite gender, that means the Togepi must be female, and Ash's Pikachu must also be male.

The Pikachu in *Pokémon - I Choose You!* is explicitly the same Pikachu as in the main anime, as it takes place in a parallel timeline that splits off from the original series' timeline. Therefore, the Pikachu in *I Choose You!* is also male.

Your main argument seems to be that Pikachu is voiced by a woman, and must therefore be female. This is not the case. It is *extremely* common for young male characters in anime/cartoons to be voiced by women. For example: Ash Ketchum has *also* been voiced by a woman - in both Japanese and English - for the last 22 years.

Comment: Huh, never realized that. Thanks for sharing these Facts! 

Comment: Although I do wonder why they didn’t even try to make Pikachu sound male in that Part. Ash sounds like he is male even though he was voiced by a Woman. Although Pikachu 100% sounded like a little Girl ‍♂️

Comment: Nancy Cartwright (born October 25, 1957) has been the voice actor of Bart Simpson on The Simpsons since  1987.  Thus her autobiography is titled My Life as a 10-year-old Boy (2000).